# ASP.NET - sharing Columns between GridViews

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dry

Is there a way to define a `<Columns>` outside of a `GridView` in my .aspx file such that I can use those `<Columns>` in multiple `GridView`s in the same page?  I have two `GridView`s that will have the same DataSource type, just with different content, and I'd rather not repeat all my customized `TemplateField`s in each.  This seems simple enough, it's just I'm new to ASP.NET.  Coming from WPF, it feels like I should be able to define my `<Columns>` in some parent "Resources" area, define its TargetType, give it a key, and then reference that key wherever I want those `<Columns>` to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is what you want, but you can create custom GridViewColumns implementation and use it. [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/How_to_create_custom_boun.aspx)